# Date validation in Swift 3

Tags: swift, date, swift3, dateformatter

How can I check whether an entered date is in `dd:mm:yyyy` format? If the user enters a wrong date, then it should display "invalid date".

Answer (score 3):

You should use `DateFormatter` to check whether your string is valid by the format given to `DateFormatter`'s `dateFormat` parameter.

```
let dateString = "31:12:2017"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd:MM:yyyy"

if dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) != nil {
    print("date is valid")
} else {
    print("date is invalid")
}
```